# AutoIncrement Hsqldb with spring not working

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing, hsqldb

I am trying to run an integration test using an embedded database. I am trying to do this with hsqldb database, leveraging the use of scripts and when I try to input my without an id, though I set my id to autoincrement I come up with a exception that doesn't like that I haven't included my id.

I have tried the same script using the HSQLDB manager and everything works well for me so I am not sure why this is happening. Spent quite sometime trying to find a solution but I figured maybe someone might have experienced this.

Here's a java class

```
package com.whot.dao;

import com.whot.domain.Hotspot;
import com.whot.repository.HotspotRespository;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.Sql;
import org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlGroup;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import static org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Contracts.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SqlGroup({
        @Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, scripts ={"classpath:create_tables.sql"}),
        @Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD, scripts = {"classpath:rollback/rollback_tables.sql"})
})



public class HotspotRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private HotspotRespository hotpsotRepo;

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager em;


    @Test
    public void TestSaveHotspot(){

       //test code goes here
    }
}
```

Here is my script

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS address (
    id BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
    street_name VARCHAR(256),
    unit INT,
    street_number INT,
    CONSTRAINT address_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

INSERT INTO address(id, street_name, unit, street_number) VALUES (1, 'Ossiomo Street', -1, 2);

INSERT INTO address(street_name, unit, street_number) VALUES ('first street', 10, 780);
```

Here's the stack trace

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10094 table: ADDRESS column: ID
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.hsqldb.Table.enforceRowConstraints(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.hsqldb.Table.generateAndCheckData(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.hsqldb.Table.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.hsqldb.StatementInsert.getResult(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
```

Comment: Since the `id` column is an auto-increment, why do you pass a value in the first `INSERT` statement ?

Comment: I did that to show an example @Berger It worked when I did that but not when I took it out as in the second scenario

Answer (score 1):

Put `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` above the @Id annotated property in the entity class.